# Derivative of $\sin x^{\cos x}$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

I found this problem while studying online. When I take the derivative of $\sin x^{\cos x}$ using the rule: $$(a^x)'=a^x\ln a,$$ and using the chainrule I get: $$\sin x^{\cos x} \ln \sin x\cdot(-\sin x).$$ 
However in the page I found this problem on, the solution is listed as: $$\sin x^{\cos x}\left(\frac {\cos^2x} {\sin x}-\sin x\ln(\sin x)\right)$$
I don't believe my solution was wrong but I'd like to know how to get to the solution that's on the page. 
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: See [How would I differentiate $\sin{x}^{\cos{x}}?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545203/how-would-i-differentiate-sinx-cosx)

Comment: Sorry, I searched this problem by the term **derivative** instead of **differentiation** and it displayed no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that the rule you are using assumes $a$ is a constant. Whilst your problem is most definitely not.
$$
u(x) = f(x)^{g(x)} = \mathrm{e}^{g\ln f}
$$
which means
$$
u'(x) = \left(g'(x) \ln f(x) + \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}f'(x)\right)f(x)^{g(x)}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note your answer is incorrect, since the formula you quoted requires $a$ to be a constant

Let $y=\sin x^{\cos x}$

$$\ln y = \cos x\ln(\sin x)$$

$$\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = -\sin x\ln(\sin x)+\cos x\cdot\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \sin x^{\cos x}\bigg(\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin x} -\sin x\ln(\sin x)\bigg) $$

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you start here:

$(\sin x)^{cos x}  = e^{\cos x \ln (\sin x)}$

As you differentiate don't lose track of the product rule and the chain rule.

$\frac d{dx} e^{\cos x \ln \sin x} = e^{\cos x \ln \sin x} \frac d{dx} (\cos x\ln (\sin x))\\
e^{\cos x \ln \sin x} (-\sin x \ln (\sin x) + \frac {cos x}{\sin x}(\frac d{dx} \sin x)\\
e^{\cos x \ln \sin x} (-\sin x \ln (\sin x) + \frac {cos^2 x}{\sin x})$

And finally we can simplfy $e^{\cos x \ln \sin x}$ back again

$(\sin x)^{cos x} (-\sin x \ln (\sin x) + \frac {cos^2 x}{\sin x})$

Answer (score 1):

$${ \left( { \sin { x }  }^{ \cos { x }  } \right)  }^{ \prime  }={ \left( { e }^{ \cos { x } \ln { \sin { x }  }  } \right)  }^{ \prime  }={ e }^{ \cos { x } \ln { \sin { x }  }  }\left( -\sin { x } \ln { \left( \sin { x }  \right) +\frac { \cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  }{ \sin { x }  }  }  \right) \\ $$

Answer (score 0):

Write the function as
$$
y=e^{\cos x \ln(\sin x)}
$$

so

$$
y'=e^{\cos x \ln(\sin x)}\left[-\sin x \ln(\sin x) +\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \cos x \right]
$$